# Apache Spark FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to play a little bit with apache-spark cluster mode.
So my cluster consists of a driver in my machine and a worker and manager in host machine(separate machine).

I send a textfile using `sparkContext.addFile(filepath)` where the filepath is the path of my text file in local machine for which I get the following output:

```
INFO Utils: Copying /home/files/data.txt to /tmp/spark-b2e2bb22-487b-412b-831d-19d7aa96f275/userFiles-147c9552-1a77-427e-9b17-cb0845807860/data.txt

INFO SparkContext: Added file /home/files/data.txt at http://192.XX.XX.164:58143/files/data.txt with timestamp 1457432207649
```

But when I try to access the same file using `SparkFiles.get("data.txt")`, I get the path to file in my driver instead of worker.
I am setting my file like this

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-play").setMaster("spark://192.XX.XX.172:7077");
    conf.setJars(new String[]{"jars/SparkWorker.jar"});
    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    sparkContext.addFile("/home/files/data.txt");
    List<String> file =sparkContext.textFile(SparkFiles.get("data.txt")).collect();
```

I am getting FileNotFoundException here.

Comment: Could you please write what the output of `SparkFiles.get("data.txt")` is?

Comment: Hey mark the output is /tmp/spark-b2e2bb22-412b-831d-19d7aa96f275/userFiles-147c9552-1a77-427e-9b17-cb0845807860/data.txt

Answer (score 2):

I have recently faced the same issue and hopefully my solution can help other people solve this issue.

We know that when you use `SparkContext.addFile(<file_path>)`, it sends the file to the automatically created working directories in the driver node (in this case, your machine) as well as the worker nodes of the Spark cluster.

The block of code that you shared where you are using `SparkFiles.get("data.txt")` is being executed on the driver, so it returns the path to the file on the driver, instead of the worker. But, the task is being run on the worker and path to the file on the driver does not match the path to the file on the worker because the driver and worker nodes have different working directory paths. Hence, you get the `FileNotFoundException`.

There is a workaround to this problem without using any distributed file system or ftp server. You should put the file in your working directory on your host machine. Then, instead of using `SparkContext.get("data.txt")`, you use `"./data.txt"`.

```
List<String> file = sparkContext.textFile("./data.txt").collect();
```

Now, even though there is a mismatch of working directory paths between the spark driver and worker nodes, you will NOT face `FileNotFoundException` since you are using a relative path to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main issue is that you are trying to read the file via the `textFile` method. What is inside the brackets of the `textFile` method is executed in the driver program. In the worker node only the code tobe run against an RDD is performed. When you type `textFile` what happens is that in your driver program it is created a RDD object with a trivial associated DAG.But nothing happens in the worker node.

Thus, when you're trying to collect the data, the worker is asked to read the file at the URL you've passed to `textFile`, which is told by the driver. Since your file is in the local filesystem of the driver and the worker node doesn't have access to it, you get the `FileNotFoundException`.

The solution is to make the file available to the worker node by putting it into a distributed filesystem as HDFS or via (s)ftp or you have to trasfer the file into the worker node before running the Spark job and then you have to put as an argument of `textFile` the path of the file in the worker filesystem.

Comment: I specified file schema and tried too. But the path returned by SparkFiles.getRootDirectory() is the path of file in driver and not in worker. FYI the worker is in a separate host machine. I am just trying to do this without hdfs. addFile() API sends the file to worker node successfully and the file is there in the work path of the node.

Comment: Sorry, I've not understood what you meant. I know that your worker node is different from your driver. You see the path in the driver because you are looking at the log in the driver. If you look at the output of the log in your worker you'll see the path of the file in the worker. How did you specified the schema in your code?

Comment: I did try using "file:/"+SparkFiles.get()

Comment: Actually, I can't figure out why it is not working. Anyway, what you are doing and what you want to do isn't really clear to me: you are transferring over the network the file to the worker only to read it and collect it back to the driver? What is your goal? Maybe we can look for another more straightforward way...

Comment: Simple my goal is to perform RDD operations on a text file so I tried it using sc.textFile() method. But as the worker is a different machine and the worker does not have direct access to the driver machine, I am doing sc.addFiles() method and sending the file to worker. In reality the SparkFiles.get() should return me the worker path instead it's returning the driver copy of the file.

Comment: Yes, but this is not the right way to do that. `addFile` is thought for lookup files or things like that which have to be available on all worker nodes. It is not thought to be used for creating an RDD. Moreover the code code `SparkFiles.get("data.txt")` is executed in the context of the driver thread. The only way you have to do what you are doing is accessing a distributed filesystem as HDFS or making the file available to the worker node via ftp or other similar protocols. I update the answer properly.